# Method orderBy does not exist.Pagination in Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Currently i am trying to pagination in eloquent Relationship.it work fine.this is my code below.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->paginate(4);
```

but when i  Pagination in Eloquent Relationship. it display Method orderBy does not exist. in front view index blade i am looping category post to order the post by asc to show latest post. how can i slove it.

```
@foreach($samachar->posts()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(1)->get() as $post)
```

Comment: `return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(4);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `orderBy` in relationship definition

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(4);
```

I don't understand why you use `paginate()` in relationship definition

Answer (score 0):

(2/2) ErrorException
Method orderBy does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\kochilafm\resources\views\front\index.blade.php)

in Macroable.php (line 74)